# PHP - Codeigniter set views datetime to locale

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, timezone, locale

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have tons of `date('format',strtotime(unixtimestamp))` methods in my views.

So when user choose his own language and I would like to automatically convert all datetimes to locale time zone for all my views.

Is there any recursive way to make this possible?

```
The infos i get from users is their selected language:
it = Italian
fr = French
es = Espanol
etc... so i get lang key codes
```

I sincerely can't get anything out of my head.

Any help appreciated, really. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you store the [timezone preference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), you could use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

**Note:** I'm not familiar with CodeIgnitor, but so long as you set this in a bootstrap or config script, that is before you call `date()`, this will automatically display all dates in the set locale.

Comment: yes sorry, check i edited my question with infos i get from users probably i need somenthing different !?

Comment: oh sorry note i'm using php method datetime() to ouput dates, so i'm not using the date helper

Comment: The `DateTime` class you mean? Again, I'm not familiar with CodeIgnitor.

Comment: eheh nope, php datetime() php native ;)

Comment: There is no such function, `datetime()` in PHP.

Comment: oh gosh my mistake pfff i mean date('format',strtotime(unixtimestamp))